# How to run a cron job every 10 seconds in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, whenever

I am trying to run a cron job in every 10 seconds that runs a piece of code. I have used an approach which requires running a code and making it sleep for 10 seconds, but it seems to make drastically degrading the app performance. I am using whenever gem, which run every minute and sleeps for 10 seconds. How can I achieve the same w/o using sleep method. Following is my code.

```
every 1.minute do
  runner "DailyNotificationChecker.send_notifications"
end
```

---

```
class DailyNotificationChecker
    def self.send_notifications
        puts "Triggered send_notifications"
        expiry_time = Time.now + 57
        while (Time.now < expiry_time)
            if RUN_SCHEDULER == "true" || RUN_SCHEDULER == true
              process_notes
            end
          sleep 10 #seconds
        end
```

---

```
    def self.process_notes
        notes = nil
        time = Benchmark.measure do
          Note.uncached do
            notes = Note.where(status: false)
            notes.update_all(status: true)
          end
        end
        puts "time #{time}"
      end
    end
```

Objective of my code is to change the boolean status of objects to **true** which gets checked every 10 seconds. This table has 2 million records.

Comment: It sound like you need a daemon running on the background instead of a cronjob starting every 10 seconds. I'm not sure why you don't want the `sleep` though, I think that starting a new process every 10 seconds isn't better than just a while with a sleep (it has to start the whole rails app every 10 seconds!!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) gem. It runs in a separate process. The configuration is pretty simple.

```rb
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job') { DailyNotificationChecker.process_notes }
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a Sidekiq background jobs for this. With the [`sidekiq-scheduler`](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) gem you can run ordinary sidekiq jobs schedules in whatever internal you need. Bonus points for having a web-interface to handle and monitor the jobs via the Sidekiq gem.

Comment: Hi Spickermann. You have astonishing stackoverflow reputation. Would it require to install redis? And in your opinion can you tell me if sleep command has adverse effect on application?

Comment: Because sidekiq's default database is redis this solution would require to install redis. That might be an overkill for your application, but in my experience, most apps will sooner or later need background processing anyway. Having a process or thread that sleep 10 seconds will not affect other processes or thread. But it requires you to have this thread running all the time although it sleeps most of the time.